# C++ Deleting a File io line using a number

Tags: c++, file

Im creating a todo list right now using file io and every task I add to the list has a serial number attached to the beginning of it, what im trying to accomplish is how I can use that serial number as a way of deleting that entire line of text in the file. I know deleting a line requires a temp file and renaming it (at least from what ive read up on) but i cant manage to get it to delete the line i want, or it will only delete the serial number instead.

For example if I want to delete the second line i would enter "- 2" and it would do so. This is my code so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

// Class for our add, delete, and view functions.
class Todo {

public:
    void add (string);
    void del (string);
    void view();
};

int main () {

Todo l;
string item;
char command;

    lPlaceholder:
    cout << "\t\tYour ToDo List" << endl;
    cout << "Press + then enter your item to add to the list" << endl;
    cout << "Press - then enter your items serial number to remove" << endl;
    cout << "Press ? to display all items in your list" << endl;
    cout << "Press x to quit the program" << endl;
    cin >> command;


if (command == '+' || command == '-') {
    getline(cin, item);
}

// Simple menu
switch(command){
case '+': l.add(item); goto lPlaceholder;   
case '-': l.del(item); goto lPlaceholder;
case '?': l.view();    goto lPlaceholder;
case 'x': exit (0);
default: cout << "Invalid choice.\n";
}
}


// Add function
void Todo::add(string item) 
{
char command;
string info;
int serial = 1;

ifstream in;
in.open ("ToDo List.txt");
while (getline(in, info))
serial ++;

time_t rawtime;
struct tm*timeinfo;
time (&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

ofstream f;
f.open ("ToDo List.txt", ios::app);
f<< serial <<" "<< item << " " << timeinfo->tm_mon << " " << timeinfo->tm_mday << " " << (timeinfo->tm_year + 1900) << endl;
f.close();
cout << endl;
cout << "New item added to the list";
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
}

// Delete function
void Todo::del(string item)
{
string info;
ifstream myfile("ToDo List.txt");
ofstream newfile("temp.txt");

if (myfile.is_open()) {
    while (getline (myfile, item)) {
        n = item;
        if (n.find(item)!=std::string::npos) {
            newfile<<n;
        }
    }
    myfile.close();
    remove("ToDo List.txt")
    rename("temp.txt", "ToDo List.txt");
}
}

void Todo::view()
{

}
```

Comment: And what have you given your code as input, what is the current and expected output? Please read [mcve].

Comment: for input i use "+ (whatever text here after the +)" and it inputs into the file with a serial number attached to it at the beginning, with the current date being added after the line. (So first input is 1, second input is 2, etc...) That works just fine with my add function, I just cant get my delete function to delete the full line.

Comment: You should [edit] the question to add more information. Also read the MCVE link I linked above, your posted code has too much unrelated parts (user input parsing, etc.)

Comment: @Spazzdazz: that is because your `delete()` method has logic bugs in it. Its search loop is wiping out the `item` parameter that you are looking for (change `while (getline (myfile, item))` to `while (getline (myfile, n))`, and then rename `n` to `info`), and it is also not ending each saved item in the new file with a line break, so it corrupts the new file.

Answer (score 0):

To delete an item, simply read the input file line-by-line, writing each line to the new output file, ignoring the line that contains the serial number you want to "delete".  Your items begin with a serial number, so it is very easy to find.

Try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

// Class for our add, delete, and view functions.
class Todo {
public:
    void add (string);
    void del (int);
    void view();
};

int main () {
    Todo l;
    string item;
    char command;
    int serial;

    do
    {
        cout << "\t\tYour ToDo List" << endl;
        cout << "Press + then enter an item to add to the list" << endl;
        cout << "Press - then enter an item serial number to remove" << endl;
        cout << "Press ? to display all items in the list" << endl;
        cout << "Press x to quit the program" << endl;
        cin >> command;

        if (command == '+' || command == '-') {
            getline(cin, item);
        }

        // Simple menu
        switch (command)
        {
            case '+':
                l.add(item);
                break;

            case '-': {
                istringstream(item) >> serial;
                l.del(serial);
                break;
            }

            case '?':
                l.view();
                break;

            case 'x':
                return 0;

            default:
                cout << "Invalid choice." << endl;
                break;
        }
    }
    while (true);

    return 0;
}

// Add function
void Todo::add(string item) 
{
    string info;
    int next_serial = 1;
    int serial;

    ifstream in("ToDo List.txt");
    while (getline(in, info))
    {
        istringstream(info) >> serial;
        if (serial >= next_serial)
            next_serial = serial + 1;
    }
    in.close();

    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm *timeinfo;
    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

    ofstream f("ToDo List.txt", ios::app);
    f << next_serial << " " << item << " " << timeinfo->tm_mon << " " << timeinfo->tm_mday << " " << (timeinfo->tm_year + 1900) << endl;
    f.close();

    cout << endl;
    cout << "New item added to the list";
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

// Delete function
void Todo::del(int item)
{
    ifstream myfile("ToDo List.txt");
    if (!myfile.is_open()) return;

    ofstream newfile("temp.txt");
    if (!newfile.is_open()) return;

    string info;
    int serial;
    bool deleted = false;

    while (getline (myfile, info))
    {
        if (!deleted)
        {
            istringstream(info) >> serial;
            if (serial == item)
            {
                deleted = true;
                continue;
            }
        }

        newfile << info << endl;
    }

    if (deleted)
    {
        myfile.close();
        newfile.close();

        remove("ToDo List.txt")
        rename("temp.txt", "ToDo List.txt");

        cout << endl;
        cout << "Item removed from the list";
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Item not found in the list";
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void Todo::view()
{
    ifstream myfile("ToDo List.txt");
    string info;

    while (getline (myfile, info))
        cout << info << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Remy, I need to get into the habit of using if statements with return as well after mt if/ofstreams. Im still relatively new to file io so this is a great help, this is the first time ive actually had to copy from a previous file into a new file.

Comment: You might want to consider using a container like `std::vector` to hold your items. Load the file into the container when the app starts up, then manipulate its items in memory as needed while the app is running, and then save the container to file when exiting the app.

Comment: Thanks @Remy Lebeau! Ill keep that in mind next time I am writing to files, I havent used vectors much but that seems like it could be much simpler.